# cannot cast 'androidx.fragment.app.Fragment' to 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment'

Tags: java, android-studio, fragment, augmented-reality

Inconvertible types; `cannot cast 'androidx.fragment.app.Fragment' to 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment'`

Here is my code:
[image: code screenshot]

I have `import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment;`
but still get an error. Please help.